# Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session') ->getLastRealOrderId(); is not working

Tags: magento-1.8

I'm using paypal standard as a payment system and want to get the last order id and for that I'm using `age::getSingleton('checkout/session') ->getLastRealOrderId();`

But this is not giving me the last placed order ID., I've checked in the modal `app/code/local/Mage/Paypal/Model/ipn.php` in method `_registerPaymentCapture` I've tried saving the order into a session so that I can get it on success page...but that is also not working.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: hey can you check,$this->_order is give order object using $this->_order->getId();

Comment: don't you see an order no. on the order success page?

Comment: @MTM I've a custom order success page.

Comment: @AmitBera yes $this->_order->getId(); this works in model ipn.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ravi,there place where this session is place

**First ,** `this session variable` is `set`  at  `Mage_Checkout_Model_Type_Onepage`  on function `saveOrder` here thus `session variable is set for first time` before  redirecting to paygate way.

**For Paypal**,if customer `is cancel this payment at paypal site` and comes `to magento paypal cancel url then on cancelAction`     `this session variable is destroyed`.So,you do not get `realorderid` .beacuse using  **->unsLastOrderId()** destroy realorderid .

Check at

```
Mage_Paypal_Controller_Express_Abstract
Mage_Paypal_PayflowadvancedController
Mage_Paypal_PayflowController
Mage_Paypal_StandardController
```

Comment: Thanks amit you i found the place saveOrder where lastorderid wa setting up and did the same in my code.